# Powershell .ToUpper and remove spaces

Tags: string, powershell, syntax, uppercase

After a lot of blood, sweat, tears, and amazing assistance from folks on these boards I finally have my code working, but I need a little help with trimming and capitalizing. I sort of understand how to change something after it is already created, but I'd rather have it converted before it is committed.

Is this the correct syntax:

```
#Create Security Groups
    $GroupParams1= @{
        'Name' = "FS-$NAME-RW".ToUpper
        'SamAccountName' = "FS-$NAME-RW".ToUpper
        'GroupCategory' = "Security"
        'GroupScope' = "Global"
        'DisplayName' = "$NAME Read-Write Access"
        'Path' = "OU=$LOCATION,OU=FILE SHARE GROUPS,OU=Security Groups,DC=esg,DC=intl"
    'Description' = "Members of this group have read-write access to $Path."
}
```

If that is correct, how do I remove the spaces that MIGHT be added due to the $Name Input?

In this instance I want to be able to have a folder created called "Test Share 123," but I'm wanting the AD group created by this to be called "FS-TESTSHARE123-R" and "FS-TESTSHARE123-RW" instead of "FS-Test Share 123-R."

Also, any other suggestions on my script?

```
$Parent = read-host -prompt "Enter full parent path that will contain the new folder (ie. \\eccofs01\Groups\ECCO IT\)"
$Name = read-host -prompt "Enter New Folder Name."
$Path = "$($parent)$($Name)"
$Location = read-host -prompt "Enter the AD Security Group Location (i.e. Global, Americas, Europe, Asia Pacific)"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Create Security Groups
$GroupParams1= @{
    'Name' = "FS-$NAME-RW" 
    'SamAccountName' = "FS-$NAME-RW" 
    'GroupCategory' = "Security"
    'GroupScope' = "Global"
    'DisplayName' = "$NAME Read-Write Access"
    'Path' = "OU=$LOCATION,OU=FILE SHARE GROUPS,OU=Security Groups,DC=esg,DC=intl"
    'Description' = "Members of this group have read-write access to $Path."
}

New-ADGroup @GroupParams1

$GroupParams2= @{
    'Name' = "FS-$NAME-R" 
    'SamAccountName' = "FS-$NAME-R" 
    'GroupCategory' = "Security"
    'GroupScope' = "Global"
    'DisplayName' = "$NAME Read-Write Access"
    'Path' = "OU=$LOCATION,OU=FILE SHARE GROUPS,OU=Security Groups,DC=esg,DC=intl"
    'Description' = "Members of this group have read access to $Path"
}

New-ADGroup @GroupParams2

# Create New Folder
New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory

#Create All ACEs (permission sets) and Set ACL on the new folder
function New-Ace {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [Security.Principal.NTAccount]$Account,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
    [Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$Permissions = 'ReadAndExecute',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
    [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]$InheritanceFlags = 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
    [Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]$PropagationFlags = 'None',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
    [Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]$Type = 'Allow'
  )

  New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    $Account, $Permissions, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $Type
  )
}

$domain = 'ESG.INTL'

$administrators = ([wmi]"Win32_Sid.Sid='S-1-5-32-544'").AccountName

$acl = Get-Acl $path

$administrators, "$domain\Domain Admins" | ForEach-Object {
  $acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $_ 'FullControl'))
}
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace "$domain\FS-$NAME-RW" 'Modify'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace "$domain\FS-$NAME-R" 'ReadAndExecute'))

Set-Acl $path $acl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to work for me :

```
'Name' = "FS-$($NAME.replace(' ',''))-RW".toupper()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That helps a ton. I was thinking of it backwards and trying to capitalize first which was making it confusing...

Comment: You're welcome! First time around here with an account, glad I can help! My code actually missed a parens but I guess you figured that out.

Comment: Yeah, I ran it and saw the error. No worries though. :D

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parens on the ToUpper call

```
'Name' = "FS-$NAME-RW".ToUpper()
```

That should help.  If you need to trim trailing spaces, you can chain the calls together (though this one doesn't have trailing spaces)....

```
'Name' = "FS-$NAME-RW".ToUpper().TrimEnd(' ')
```

Comment: I think he wants to remove any spaces in the string, not just at the end, in which case he can use `.Replace()`, example: `'Name' = "FS-$($NAME.Trim().Replace(' ', '').ToUpper())-RW"`

Comment: It seems the .Trim would not be needed if I'm replacing all of the spaces. Am I not understanding that correctly?